# How would I loop these numbers in reverse?

Tags: c++

I need to print the following numbers to the screen using a loop 20,15,10,5,3.

How can I display these numbers in this order since there is a subtraction of 5 every time except for the 3?

```
#include <iostream>
int main2() {
    for (int num = 20; num <= 3; num -= 5) {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop your iteration at 5, and manually subtract down by 2, then print it out.

Comment: This might be a copy-pasting error, but your condition should be `num >= 3`, not `num <= 3`

Comment: This is a coding puzzle that expects you to know how `std::max` works and how to use it. Do you know how to use `std::max`?